Cannot get Fletchers checksum correct in UBX protocol using C#
I am working with the UBX protocol on a ublox 6 GPS module. The ubx string has a checksum and the algorithm used is the 8-Bit Fletcher Algorithm as shown on Wikipedia. The ublox documentation is found here look at page 86 for the checksum info which I also write below.
I believe the algorithm works as follows:
•   Buffer[N] contains the data over which the checksum is to be calculated.
•   The two CK_ values are 8-Bit unsigned integers, only.
•   If implementing with larger-sized integer values, mask both CK_A and CK_B with 0xFF after both operations in the loop.
Buffer[N]
CK_A = 0, CK_B = 0
For(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
CK_A = CK_A + Buffer[i]
CK_B = CK_B + CK_A
}

I have implemented this to check the data I receive from a u-blox 6 GPS module is correct using the following code. The data that the checksum is worked out on it without the first two bytes which are sync characters and the last two which are the checksum characters.
I send the data into the function as a string and convert it to a Byte array. This seems to work OK. I then go through the Byte array using the algorithm above and create the first and second checksum characters.
public static string Check_Fletcher_checksum(string myData)
{
   ushort sum1 = 0;
   ushort sum2 = 0;

   string existing_checksum = myData.Substring(myData.Length - 4, 4);

   //take off existing checksum and sync chars (1st two and last two bytes.)
   myData = myData.Substring(4, myData.Length - 8); 

   int NumberChars = myData.Length;
   byte[] data = new byte[NumberChars/2]; //create array of bytes

   for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2) //put string in byte array
   {
       data[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(myData.Substring(i, 2), 16);
   }

   foreach (byte b in data) //calculate Fletchers checksum
   {
       sum1 = (ushort)((sum1 + b) % 255); 
      sum2 = (ushort)((sum2 + sum1) % 255);
   }

   string checksum = sum1.ToString("X2") + sum2.ToString("X2"); //add leading zero if req

   //Check the checksum and tell user if correct or not.
   if (existing_checksum == checksum)
   {
       return "Checksum = " + existing_checksum + " is correct";
   }

   return "Checksum = " + existing_checksum + " is incorrect should be = " + checksum;
  }

I have misunderstood something as I cannot always get the correct answer. I think it has something to do with this needing to be 8bit and that is why I mask sum1 and sum2 with 255 each time through the loop. If the data never exceeds 255 then it works OK but when I need to use the mask it is not correct. Usually out by a small amount.
What I have tried:
•   I have tried the data as int, sbyte as well but they do not give the correct answer either.
•   I also tried masking with 256 and 255 and while 256 is better in some respects neither is correct for all data. 1s and 2s complement?
•   When I work it out with pen and paper, I also do not get it correct. What am I not seeing please?
Example data:
B56206010800F0000000000000010024

For this the checksum is worked out on the data 06010800F000000000000001 and my function says the checksum is 012C when it should be 0024
B56206010800F0040001000000010545B5620501020006010F38244750524D432C2C562C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C4E2A3533
Use data as 06010800F0040001000000010545B5620501020006010F38244750524D432C2C562C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C4E2A  check sum I calculate is 3E66 and not 3533
B5620A0400000E34

For this we use the data as 0A040000 and the check sum is indeed 0E34.
